# Choosing the MD Run-Time Library version for cross compiling

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dynamic-linking, visual-c++-2005, microsoft-runtime-library

I need to cross compile using Visual 2005 in Windows 10 to deploy in a Windows NT. I compiled (in WIN10) using the MT Run-Time library and I could execute some applications in windows NT correctly, but now I need to use the MD, instead of the MT. Could I say to the compiler which MD version link against to? using some Macro like WIN32_WINNT or similar?

Thanks!!

Comment: not in vs 2005, it can only use the 2005 runtime, why do you want to use a different version?

Comment: Because the target (Win NT) system has an older runtime than the host used to compile (Win 10)

Comment: yeah but vs 2005 is pretty unlikely to produce code for an OS that was released 10 years after it was. Have you tried running your code on NT?

Comment: though it doesn't look like vs 2005 supports nt: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2661358/minimum-service-pack-levels-for-microsoft-vc-redistributable-packages

Comment: this states static linking is the only option: http://www.malsmith.net/blog/visual-c-visual-history/

Comment: Yeah, I tried and I can execute code but using the Static Run Time Library, but due to the dependencies of the project I cannot use the Static version anymore.

Comment: You'll need to change your dependencies to use the static runtime or stop supporting an OS Microsoft stopped supporting 15 years ago